# How to use HtmlAgilityPack to receive JSON data from script

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

My question is about the following html: https://pastebin.com/qT97gBh5

I download the HTML Site by using

```
            var url = "https://www.twitch.tv/monstercat";
            var web = new HtmlWeb();
            var doc = web.Load(url);
```

Now the only thing that interests me is the JSON Data off the following section.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">[{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"VideoObject","thumbnailUrl":["https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/previews-ttv/live_user_monstercat-{width}x{height}.jpg"],"embedUrl":"https://player.twitch.tv/?channel=monstercat&player=facebook&autoplay=true","name":"Monstercat - Twitch","description":"Non Stop Music - Monstercat Radio ","videoQuality":"1080p","publication":{"@type":"BroadcastEvent","isLiveBroadcast":true,"startDate":"03/29/2020 19:04:06"},"author":{"@type":"Person","name":"Monstercat","url":"https://www.twitch.tv/monstercat"},"uploadDate":"03/29/2020 19:04:06"}]</script>
```

How would i use HtmlAgilityPack to use the xpath 
`/html/head/script[2]` to receive the JSON Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can search about agility pack in c# and after that use agility to get this X path

```
/html/head/script[2]
```

now you have a json string. convert json to property with  newtonsoft(add this package with Nuget).congratulation so you can read description in your class.

Comment: How would i use HtmlAgilityPack to use the xpath /html/head/script[2] to receive the JSON Data?

Comment: Take a look at this :https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/9b86d4/getting-started-with-html-agility-pack/